# UTF-8 encoding on filehandle in Perl

Tags: perl, utf-8, filehandle

I'm applying UTF-8 encoding to STDIN and STDOUT. However how do I make sure that I apply UTF-8 encoding to the file that I pass to my code below (<> will read from a file instead of STDIN if a text file is passed on the command line) in as few lines as possible.

```
use open qw(:std :utf8)

while (<>) {
    print;
}
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I read UTF-8 with diamond operator (<>)?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/519309/how-do-i-read-utf-8-with-diamond-operator)

Answer (score 1):

According to the `open` pragma's documentation, you've already got the behavior you want:

> The `open` pragma serves as one of the interfaces to declare default "layers" (also known as "disciplines") for all I/O. Any two-argument `open`, `readpipe` (aka `qx//`) and similar operators found within the lexical scope of this pragma will use the declared defaults.  Even three-argument opens may be affected by this pragma when they don't specify IO layers in MODE.

The [perlop](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlop.html) documentation tells us that `while (<>) { ... }` is equivalent to

> ```
>    unshift(@ARGV, '-') unless @ARGV;
>    while ($ARGV = shift) {
>      open(ARGV, $ARGV);
>      while (<ARGV>) {
>        ... # code for each line
>      }
>    }
> ```

Comment: So then the filehandle is treated as if it's coming from STDIN. I'm reading the perlop documentation, but it doesn't explicitly state that, does it?

Comment: @syker No, it uses the `ARGV` filehandle as quoted above. The quoted excerpt from the `open` pragma's documentation specifies that it applies to *all* I/O.