# My Perl regexp-matching code doesn't work properly

Tags: regex, perl, utf-8

I have a problem with script perl which doesn't work properly. The script take 2 file on argument :

The first is a lexical:

```
a
à
abaissa
abaissable
abaissables
abaissai
abaissaient
abaissais
abaissait
abaissâmes
```

The second is a corpus:

```
ASEAN New Markets (renommé « Equity ASEAN » à partir du 24 juin 2011), Gems World, Emerging Internai Demand (renommé « Equity Emerging Internai\
 Demand » à partir du 24 juin 2011), Emerging Markets (intégré au Compartiment « Emerging World » le 24 juin 2011) et Emerging World (renommé «\
 Equity Emerging World » à partir du 24 juin 2011).
Les Actions de catégorie « B » ne sont pas soumises à des Frais sur vente réglés d'avance (c'est-à-dire des Frais sur vente qui réduisent le mo\
ntant de la souscription au Fonds d'un investisseur) mais sont soumises à des FVDE prélevés sur les rachat d'Actions de catégorie « B » effectu\
és dans les quatre (4) années suivant la date d'achat (qui, pour les Actions de catégorie « B » acquises le 29 février lors de n'importe quelle\
 année, seront réputées avoir été achetées le jour précédent) comme suit :
Les Actions de catégorie « B » peuvent être échangées à la valeur liquidative par Action des Actions de catégorie « B » du Portefeuille sans qu\
'aucun Frais de vente ne soit prélevé à ce moment-là.
« Jour ouvrable » :
Les « transactions couvertes » comprennent les prêts ou extensions de crédit, les achats d'actifs et certains autres types de transactions (y c\
ompris les transactions sur produits dérivés et les garanties) qui entraîneraient pour les entités bancaires ou leurs sociétés affiliées un ris\
que de crédit par rapport à des fonds gérés par leurs sociétés affiliées.
«CSSF» désigne la Commission de Surveillance du Secteur Financier.
« Jour de négociation » :
«Directive 78/660/CEE» (Directive 78/660/EEC) désigne la directive 78/660/CEE du 25 juillet 1978 fondée sur l’Article 54 paragraphe 3 g) du Tra\
ité concernant les comptes annuels de certaines formes de sociétés, telle que modifiée.
les « démarcheurs » ou les « commissions d'indication de clients » pour avoir orienté les investisseurs vers les Portefeuilles, Comptes client/\
GS et autres produits ;
« Global Diversified Equity » - Ce Compartiment vise l'appréciation du capital sur le moyen et long terme en investissant principalement dans u\
n portefeuille diversifié d'actions et d'instruments apparentés à des actions émis par des sociétés du monde entier.
```

And the script:

```
use strict;
use utf8;
open(LEX, "<$ARGV[0]" ) or die "Usage: ./script PATH_TO_LEXIQUE PATH_TO_CORPUS\nAn error occured, open: $!";

my $tmp = "";


while ( <LEX> )
{
    $tmp = $_;

    open(CORPUS, "<$ARGV[1]" ) or die "Usage: ./script PATH_TO_LEXIQUE PATH_TO_CORPUS\nAn error occured, open: $!";

    S: while ( <CORPUS> )
    {
        if ($_ =~ m/$tmp/)
        {
            print "Matched !";
    }
        last S if $_ =~ m/$tmp/;
    }
    if ($_ =~ m/$tmp/)
    {

    }
    else
    {
        print $tmp;
    }
    close(CORPUS);
}
close(LEX);
```

But the regular expression never match although he should do because the character "à" is present in the both document.

I tried several test and it seems that length ($tmp) with $tmp = a (first line of the lexical) equal 4 ?!
Anyone can help me please ?

Comment: Please rename the question to something more relevant

Answer (score 4):

I think the problem lies there that you are not reading the fileswith correct encodings.

Use utf8 is not for this.

[How do I read UTF-8 with diamond operator (<>)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/519309/how-do-i-read-utf-8-with-diamond-operator)

Use binmode, utf8 after you opened the file.

```
binmode LEX, ':utf8';
binmode CORPUS, ':utf8';
```

Use data::dumper to print out the actual data to check it.

use Data::Dumper;
...

```
S: while ( <CORPUS> )
{

    if ($_ =~ m/$tmp/){
        print "Matched !";
    }
    die Dumper($tmp,$_); 
    last S if $_ =~ m/$tmp/;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Lines end with a newline. You are searching for the two characters "a\n" instead of "a". Use [`chomp`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/chomp.html) to remove the trailing newlines.

Fixed, along with numerous other problems and poor code:

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use utf8;
use open ':std', ':utf8';

@ARGV == 2
    or die("Usage: ./script PATH_TO_LEXIQUE PATH_TO_CORPUS\n");

open(my $LEX, "<", $ARGV[0])
    or die("Can't open $ARGV[0]: $!\n");

WORD: while (my $word = <$LEX>) {
    chomp($word);
    my $pat = quotemeta($word);

    open(my $CORPUS, "<", $ARGV[1])
       or die("Can't open $ARGV[1]: $!\n");

    while (<$CORPUS>) {
        if (/$pat/) {
            print "Matched $word!\n";
            next WORD;
        }
    }

    print "Didn't match $word\n";
}
```

---

To debug,

1. Remove all but the first line in each file.
2. Add the following to your code:

   ```
   use Data::Dumper qw( Dumper );

   sub dump_str {
       local $Data::Dumper::Useqq = 1;
       local $Data::Dumper::Terse = 1;
       local $Data::Dumper::Indent = 0;
       return Dumper($_[0]);
   }
   ```
3. Add the following before `if (/$pat/)`:

   ```
   printf("\$_=%s; \$pat=%s\n", dump_str($_), dump_str($pat));
   ```

Comment: readline() on unopened filehandle LEX at script2.perl line 12.

Comment: Should be `<$LEX>`, not `<LEX>`. I switched from global variables to lexical variables.

Comment: I beg to differ! `Matched a!
Matched à!
Didn't match abaissa
Didn't match abaissable
Didn't match abaissables
Didn't match abaissai
Didn't match abaissaient
Didn't match abaissais
Didn't match abaissait
Didn't match abaissâmes   `

Comment: OMG at home still no match, why ?

Comment: Follow the instructions I've added and give me the output.

Answer (score 1):

Line before $tmp=$_ you need a chomp to remove eol characters

Comment: if i use chomp before $tmp=$_ and i print $tmp, it is empty