# Having problems transliterating into ASCII

Tags: perl, unicode, ascii, iconv

I'm trying to process a file that has a list of city names.  My goal is to output a list of those city names transliterated into standard ASCII.  For some reason, I just keep running into problems.  I've been poking around with both iConv and the Text::Unidecode library in Perl, and both are failing me.

Here is a sample list of city names in a file I'll call cities.txt:

```
Måløv
Magtenbølle
Zvonarëvka
Denver
Zvëzdka
New York
```

Running this through `iconv` returns the following:

`iconv -fUTF-8 -tASCII//TRANSLIT//IGNORE cities.txt`

```
Mal?v
Magtenb?lle
Zvonarevka
Denver
Zvezdka
New York
```

This does well on some of the non-ascii characters, but fails, notably on `ø` characters.  My list has several thousand entries - while I haven't actually studied the results on larger than a small sample set, I'm sure that there are other failures as well.

My perl attempt looks like this:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;
use utf8;
use Text::Unidecode;

while (<>) {
  print unidecode $_;
}
```

Output from there looks like this:

```
MAY=lA,v
MagtenbA,lle
ZvonarA<<vka
Denver
ZvA<<zdka
New York
```

Oddly enough, Perl does work if I use direct statements.  E.g.

```
...
print unidecode("Måløv");
```

will output "Malov" as I expect.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: note that `use utf8` is *not* what you needed; that just tells perl that your *source* is utf8, not the input file (though it is what makes your direct statement work)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You need to read your input as UTF-8. Per [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/519309/how-do-i-read-utf-8-with-diamond-operator), try adding

```
use open qw(:std :utf8);
```

before your `while(<>)` loop.

Comment: `<>` isn't necessarily reading from stdin; if the input file(s) are given as command line parameters `:std` isn't needed (though it is good to keep in case they aren't)

Answer (score 0):

You could also try:

```
use utf8::all;
```

[utf8::all](https://metacpan.org/module/utf8%3a%3aall) will turn on Unicode - all of it.