# UTF-8 with diamond operator (<>), part II (stdin and regex)

Tags: regex, bash, perl, utf-8, stdin

I have seen [How do I read UTF-8 with diamond operator (<>)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/519309/how-do-i-read-utf-8-with-diamond-operator), unfortunately nothing in there helps me. Consider this code, `test.pl`:

```
use 5.010;
use warnings;
use strict;
use utf8; # tell Perl that your script is written in UTF-8?
binmode(STDOUT, ":raw");
binmode(STDIN, ":raw");
#~ use open IO  => ':raw'; # nope
use open qw(:std :utf8); # nope?
use Data::Dumper;

my $reValidLine = qr/^[├│└]/;

my $line2 = "│   ├── [dr";
my @matches = $line2 =~ $reValidLine;
print Dumper(\@matches);

while(<>) {
  binmode ARGV, ':utf8';
  my $line = $_;
  my @imatches = $line =~ $reValidLine;
  print Dumper(\@imatches);
}
```

If I call this from `bash` command line, I get this:

```
$ echo "│   ├── [dr" | perl test.pl
$VAR1 = [
          1
        ];
$VAR1 = [];
```

Note that I'm piping (via `echo`) into perl's stdin, the exact same string which is `$line2` in the perl code; and the very same regex matches `$line2` - but does *not* match the same string when it comes from stdin?

Just for confirmation, here is what `hexdump` and [utfinfo.pl](http://sourceforge.net/p/sdaaubckp/code/HEAD/tree/single-scripts/utfinfo.pl) report in the very same shell:

```
$ echo "│   ├── [dr" | hexdump -C
00000000  e2 94 82 c2 a0 c2 a0 20  e2 94 9c e2 94 80 e2 94  |....... ........|
00000010  80 20 5b 64 72 0a                                 |. [dr.|
00000016

$ echo "│   ├── [dr" | perl utfinfo.pl 
Got 11 uchars
Char: '│' u: 9474 [0x2502] b: 226,148,130 [0xE2,0x94,0x82] n: BOX DRAWINGS LIGHT VERTICAL [Box Drawing]
Char: ' ' u: 160 [0x00A0] b: 194,160 [0xC2,0xA0] n: NO-BREAK SPACE [Latin-1 Supplement]
Char: ' ' u: 160 [0x00A0] b: 194,160 [0xC2,0xA0] n: NO-BREAK SPACE [Latin-1 Supplement]
Char: ' ' u: 32 [0x0020] b: 32 [0x20] n: SPACE [Basic Latin]
Char: '├' u: 9500 [0x251C] b: 226,148,156 [0xE2,0x94,0x9C] n: BOX DRAWINGS LIGHT VERTICAL AND RIGHT [Box Drawing]
Char: '─' u: 9472 [0x2500] b: 226,148,128 [0xE2,0x94,0x80] n: BOX DRAWINGS LIGHT HORIZONTAL [Box Drawing]
Char: '─' u: 9472 [0x2500] b: 226,148,128 [0xE2,0x94,0x80] n: BOX DRAWINGS LIGHT HORIZONTAL [Box Drawing]
Char: ' ' u: 32 [0x0020] b: 32 [0x20] n: SPACE [Basic Latin]
Char: '[' u: 91 [0x005B] b: 91 [0x5B] n: LEFT SQUARE BRACKET [Basic Latin]
Char: 'd' u: 100 [0x0064] b: 100 [0x64] n: LATIN SMALL LETTER D [Basic Latin]
Char: 'r' u: 114 [0x0072] b: 114 [0x72] n: LATIN SMALL LETTER R [Basic Latin]
```

So, both of them confirm the same bytes as for the right utf-8 characters.

Then, why doesn't the Perl regex match the string when its piped from stdin, and how do I get it to match?

Answer (score 1):

Well, got it to work with this change:

```
binmode(STDOUT, ":utf8");
binmode(STDIN, ":utf8");
```

... now I have:

```
$ echo "│   ├── [dr" | perl test.pl
$VAR1 = [
          1
        ];
$VAR1 = [
          1
        ];
```

... which is what I expected; unfortunately I cannot provide much understanding about reasons behind this `:)` Still, hope it might help someone...

Answer (score 1):

The problem with doing this inside your `while` loop:

```
binmode ARGV, ':utf8';
```

is that it's too late. By the time that `binmode` has executed, you've already read the first line from the filehandle. (And this particular filehandle only has one line!)

Try adding a new line character to the input and you'll see that the `binmode` does actually work for the subsequent lines.

```
echo "\n│   ├── [dr" | perl test.pl
```

Lifting `binmode ARGV, ':utf8'` out of the `while` loop won't work though because at that point the special `ARGV` filehandle won't have been opened.

Personally I'd solve this by reading the handle in `raw` mode and using the Encode module to decode the UTF-8.