# Setting diamond operator to work in binmode?

Tags: perl

Diamond operator (`<>`) works in text mode by default, is it possible to change `binmode` for it? Seems `binmode` function accepts handle only.

Comment: To add an :encoding layer, or what?

Comment: @ikegami where to add the `:encoding` layer? I'd like to use `<>` to open stream as binmode by default.

Comment: Let me rephrase: What layer are you trying to add using `binmode`?

Comment: @ikegami the default layer for binmode, :raw?

Comment: Then no. However, that will have no effect on non-Windows builds unless someone uses env var `PERLIO` or `-C` or similar (e.g. env var `PERL_UNICODE`).

Comment: None of the answers here hit the nail on the head. But the question is answered here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/519309/how-do-i-read-utf-8-with-diamond-operator
`use open qw(:std :utf8);` is the solution.

Answer (score 1):

See [perldoc perlopentut](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlopentut.html#Opening-Binary-Files):

> Binary Files
>      On certain legacy systems with what could charitably be called terminally
>      convoluted (some would say broken) I/O models, a file isn't a file--at
>      least, not with respect to the C standard I/O library. On these old
>      systems whose libraries (but not kernels) distinguish between text and
>      binary streams, to get files to behave properly you'll have to bend over
>      backwards to avoid nasty problems. On such infelicitous systems, sockets
>      and pipes are already opened in binary mode, and there is currently no way
>      to turn that off. With files, you have more options.
>
> Another option is to use the "binmode" function on the appropriate handles
>      before doing regular I/O on them:
>
> ```
>    binmode(STDIN);
>    binmode(STDOUT);
>    while (<STDIN>) { print }
> ```
>
> Passing "sysopen" a non-standard flag option will also open the file in
>      binary mode on those systems that support it. This is the equivalent of
>      opening the file normally, then calling "binmode" on the handle.
>
> ```
>    sysopen(BINDAT, "records.data", O_RDWR | O_BINARY)
>        || die "can't open records.data: $!";
> ```
>
> Now you can use "read" and "print" on that handle without worrying about
>      the non-standard system I/O library breaking your data. It's not a pretty
>      picture, but then, legacy systems seldom are. CP/M will be with us until
>      the end of days, and after.
>
> On systems with exotic I/O systems, it turns out that, astonishingly
>      enough, even unbuffered I/O using "sysread" and "syswrite" might do sneaky
>      data mutilation behind your back.
>
> ```
>    while (sysread(WHENCE, $buf, 1024)) {
>        syswrite(WHITHER, $buf, length($buf));
>    }
> ```
>
> Depending on the vicissitudes of your runtime system, even these calls may
>     need "binmode" or "O_BINARY" first. Systems known to be free of such
>     difficulties include Unix, the Mac OS, Plan 9, and Inferno.

Comment: Of course, this does not help with the OP's question regarding `ARGV`.

Answer (score 1):

`<>` is a convenience. If it only iterated through filenames specified on the command line, you could use `$ARGV` within `while (<>)` to detect when a new file was opened, `binmode` it, and then `fseek` to the beginning. Of course, this does not work in the presence of redirection (console input is a whole other story).

One solution is to detect if `@ARGV` does contain something, and open each file individual, and default to reading from `STDIN`. A rudimentary implementation of this using an iterator could be:

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl

use strict;
use warnings;
use Carp qw( croak );

my $argv = sub {
    @_ or return sub {
        my $done;
        sub {
            $done and return;
            $done = 1;
            binmode STDIN;
            \*STDIN;
        }
    }->();

    my @argv = @_;
    sub {
        @argv or return;
        my $file = shift @argv;
        open my $fh, '<', $file
            or croak "Cannot open '$file': $!";
        binmode $fh;
        $fh;
    };
}->(@ARGV);

binmode STDOUT;
while (my $fh = $argv->()) {
    while (my $line = <$fh>) {
        print $line;
    }
}
```

Note:

```
C:\...\Temp> xxd test.txt
00000000: 7468 6973 2069 7320 6120 7465 7374 0a0a  this is a test..
```

Without `binmode`:

```
C:\...\Temp> perl -e "print " test.txt | xxd
00000000: 7468 6973 2069 7320 6120 7465 7374 0d0a  this is a test..
00000010: 0d0a                                     ..
```

With the script above:

```
C:\...\Temp> perl argv.pl test.txt | xxd
00000000: 7468 6973 2069 7320 6120 7465 7374 0a0a  this is a test..
```

Same results using `perl ... < test.txt | xxd`, or piping text through `perl ...`